# gwt get array button value

Tags: gwt

My gwt project have flexTable show data of image and button on each row and coll.
But my button won't work properly. this is my current code:

```
private Button[] b = new Button[]{new Button("a"),...,new Button("j")};
private int z=0;
...
public void UpdateTabelGallery(JsArray str){
    for(int i=0; i str.length(); i++){
    b[i].setText(str.gettitle());                               
    UpdateTabelGallery(str.get(i));                   
  }
}

public void UpdateTabelGallery(GalleryData str){
  Image img = new Image();  
  img.setUrl(str.getthumburl());  

  HTML himage= new HTML("a href="+str.geturl()+">"+ img +"/a>" + b[z] );                                                        
  TabelGaleri.setWidget(y, x, himage);

//is here th right place?
  b[z].addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
  @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      Window.alert("I wan to show the clicked button text" + b[z].getText());               
    }                         
  });

  z++;
}
```

I'm still confuse where I should put my button handler. With this current code seems the clickhandler didn't work inside a looping. And if I put it outside loop its not working because I need to know which button clicked. I need to get my index button.but how? Is there any option than array button?

thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve - do you want to reuse the same buttons when you refresh the table/images?

Comment: I want to get my button index array. If I can get my index I can acess any array that connected to my data like the text of my button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you refer to 'z' in your click handler, but the value of z changes, so that when your click handler is actually called the value of z is wrong.

You need a local final variable in UpdateTabelGallery which you assign the current value of z to to allow it to be captured by the handler you create. Even better, get rid of z entirely and pass i to UpdateTableGallery:

```
public void updateTableGallery(GalleryData str, final int i){
  Image img = new Image();  
  img.setUrl(str.getthumburl());  

  HTML himage= new HTML("a href="+str.geturl()+">"+ img +"/a>" + b[i] );                                                        
  TabelGaleri.setWidget(y, x, himage);

//is here th right place?
  b[i].addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
  @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      Window.alert("I wan't to show the clicked button text" + b[i].getText());               
    }                         
  });

}
```

But what do you expect:

```
  HTML himage= new HTML("a href="+str.geturl()+">"+ img +"/a>" + b[i] );
```

to do? Aside from the incorrect HTML syntax, I don't think adding ypur button to the string will work.

Comment: wow, thanks for the sample code. you're right. the button didn't working if i put it in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I was using this method me too, then I've created a new Button with an additional argument.
When I add the ButtonArg I set also the argument:

```
Panel.add(new ButtonArg("B1", i));
...
 // Create a handler for the A-Z buttons
    class MyHandler implements ClickHandler {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
            ButtonArg btn=(ButtonArg) e.getSource();
            Window.alert("Button Text="+btn.getArgument());
        }
    }


public class ButtonArg extends Button {

int argument;

public ButtonArg(String html, int arg) {
    super(html);
    setArgument(arg);
}

    public int getArgument() {
    return argument;
}

public void setArgument(int argument) {
    this.argument = argument;
}
```

[...]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it didn't look answered and I was looking to do the same thing.  Here's one solution:

```
    public void onModuleLoad() {
    Button[] b=new Button[26];

    RootPanel rp=RootPanel.get("body");

    // Create a handler for the A-Z buttons
    class MyHandler implements ClickHandler {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
            Button btn=(Button) e.getSource();
            Window.alert("Button Text="+btn.getText());
        }
    }

    MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();

    for(int i=0;i<26;i++) {
        b[i] = new Button(String.valueOf((char)(65+i)));
        b[i].addStyleName("sendButton");
        rp.add(b[i]);
        b[i].addClickHandler(handler);
    }

    SimplePanel sPanel = new SimplePanel();
}
```